AWS - demystify 403 when creating Lambda or EC2 with profile due to not having IAM:PassRole
There are many questions regarding the 403 error when creating Lambda or EC2 with profile. Is there one stop location that clearly explain why?

403 error while creating Lambda function
AWS Lambda getting AccessDeniedException when spinning up with vpc_config
Issue uploading C# function to AWS Lambda - not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole"
Creating a Lambda Function without using PassRole permission
Why is iam:PassRole required in this project?


Cause
Those who create a Lambda function or EC2 with profile do need IAM:PassRole permission. The cause of 403 is mostly due to not having the permission.
Problem
We will not encounter the issue if a user has the Administrator Access role that has IAM:PassRole permission granted. The AWS account or role that a CI/CD uses will have the role or the permission, hence will not have the issue.
The developers will not have such role and will not get IAM:PassRole permission in an enterprise environment for the security reason.
Why is iam:PassRole required in this project?

Whenever an AWS Service assumes (uses) an IAM Role, the service must have iam:PassRole permission to grant permission to use the Role. This required to prevent users from gaining too much permission.
For example, imagine a normal (non-Admin) user who launches an Amazon EC2 instance. When launching the instance, they can nominate an IAM Role to be assigned to the instance. If this user was permitted to select any IAM Role, they could select an Admin role and assign it to the EC2 instance. They could then login to the instance and use the credentials to make API calls as an Admin. This is an unwanted "privilege escalation".

However, the developers in the DEV environment do need to and try to create a Lambda or EC2 with profile from e.g. the AWS console without IAM:PassRole permission given. Hence they encounter 403 and get confused.
Solution

How to use the PassRole permission with IAM roles


In most circumstances, you would not want your developers to associate a security team’s role to the resources they are creating, but you still want to allow them to create and pass business application roles.
You may want to give developers the ability to create roles for their applications, as long as they are safely governed. You can do this by verifying that those roles have permissions boundaries attached to them, and that they are created in a specific IAM role path. You can then allow developers to pass only the roles in that path.

Illustration of the problem and solution

